# What code is required to enable client-side decoration in Gnome 3 with X without using GTK?

Tags: c, rhel7, gnome-3, motif

Returning user here. I have a requirement to migrate a system of OpenMotif 2.3 apps currently running under RHEL5, Gnome Desktop 2.x, to Gnome 3 under RHEL7. The problem is that the apps **require** modifying the window menu, adding items on a per-window basis **and** accelerators. Currently we are required by our customer **not** to migrate to GTK or any other widget set. Customer security requirements require using gnome-shell, gdm, *et al*, so xfce or anything that uses an external process for screen locking is unusable.

I've looked at the mess that is gnome-shell, and while I've found the JavaScript that assembles the window menu, it requires access to the window property holding the customized menu. I see no way to have JavaScript call back into C code to do this. (If all else fails, I could use xprop to dump the property and go from there.)

I'm thinking client-side decoration, with all of its horrors of having to manage windows yourself, might be the solution here. I can't seem to get CSD to kick in, though, without using GTK. I've tried applying the _GTK_FRAME_EXTENTS property, but gnome-shell ignores it. I've tried _NET_FRAME_EXTENTS with equal lack of success. The Extended Window Manager Hints documents say nothing about this. Google, of course, is ripe with comments about using GtkHeaderBar and discussion of avoiding CSD, neither of which apply here. Wayland-based items are equally unworkable.

I am quite familiar with modifying & extending the Motif widget set, having done that for a good chunk of my career here. I need to know how to tell the Window Manager to lay off without making the window override-redirect.

Comment: Client side decorations are evil. Do not do it. Same goes for modifying the windows menu. All that belongs to the windows manager. If you think that your app requires to modify the windows menu, you are probably wrong. Virtually every application works fine without doing that. Put your menu elements somewhere else, either in a popup menu, or somewhere in the main menu of your application.

Comment: When the boss says "do it," you aren't allowed to be right, @HAL9000. We have been doing this for decades, and the boss won't allow any disagreement. I agree with you, but that doesn't mean a thing to this guy.

Comment: Then you have a boss that has hired you to create buggy code that only you can support. I would recommend you to demand a raise, he can't fire you.